# Format drives as NTFS and automount in Debian

Tags: debian, partition, automounting, ntfs

I am trying to completely erase and format all my drives except /dev/sda (my main SSD with Debian on it). I'm getting a few errors, and I'm not entirely sure I'm doing it correctly.

```
$ lsblk

sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
```

So `/dev/sdb` is the drive I want fully formatted into NTFS and mounted. I do this to erase partitions, MBR, and so on:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

Then I can do:

```
$ parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt
$ parted /dev/sdb p

Model: ATA WDC WD10EARS-00Y (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
```

So the drive now has a GPT partition table. Then I create the NTFS partition and print the details again:

```
$ parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ntfs 0% 100%
$ parted /dev/sdb p

Model: ATA WDC WD10EARS-00Y (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB               primary  msftdata
```

And you can see it has the full 1TB it's supposed to.

Now I should be able to either edit `/etc/fstab` or simply `mount /dev/sdb /home/1TB/`. I'll do the fstab:

```
$ blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="3608e3af-e6b3-4d63-a234-6bd53813e983" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="118c8db8-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="b2091441-279b-4013-b7b1-299de571280f" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="118c8db8-05"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="12c3cc3a-ce49-437b-b4d9-81c75a8f5d51"
```

and edit `/etc/fstab` to include the PARTUUID:

```
PARTUUID=12c3cc3a-ce49-437b-b4d9-81c75a8f5d51 /home/1TB/ ntfs defaults
```

and finally I can mount it:

```
$ mount -a
```

But then I get an error:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1 missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
> In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.

I've searched for solutions and why it might be wrong, but I simply can't figure out why it's not working. I do have `nfs-common` and `cifs-utils` installed. I just want to format my drive(s), make a single NTFS partition, and then mount them using fstab.

Comment: Have you tried using gparted to format?

Comment: @MichaelCorleone Nope, what would the difference be between gparted and parted in terms of what I did and what you can?

Comment: you must first format the partition and after you can be able to mount it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that there is no filesystem.

So you must first format the partition and after you can be able to mount it.

Run this command:

`mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1`

The `-f` means fast format

I also advice you to check if the package `ntfs-3g` is present on your machine, if no install it and change the entries in your `/etc/fstab` from `ntfs` to `ntfs-3g`

The `ntfs` that you are using in the fstab has limited functionality

Quoting from [gentoo wiki about ntfs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NTFS)

> Be aware: as of November, 2017, the mainlined NTFS kernel driver has very limited functional support for NTFS. The kernel configuration information defines support as "partial, but safe". This driver can overwrite existing files but is not capable of file or directory creation, deletion, or renaming.[1](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NTFS) Most NTFS users will want to to enable the FUSE powered version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mount a partition.  You need to create a filesystem inside that partition first.  Use mkntfs to do so.  Then you can mount that filesystem.

Comment: What? How would I go on about that?

Comment: there is a tool called mkntfs.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, please post an answer or tell me where I've failed.

Comment: You forgot to create a filesystem on your partition.  Clear enough?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Please try to explain your proposed solution expanding the answer and not in comments where possible. Better quality answers will get more upvotes too.